# Multiple counts in different colums

Tags: count, multiple-columns, conditional-formatting

i have this little problem i´m unable to fix.

i have this query:

Select  DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%M')as Month, count( distinctrow terminal ) as NT2023
FROM journal where operacion = 'venta' and year(fecha)='2022' GROUP by DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%m')

and i get 2 columns, 1 with the month, and another with the amount of terminals active for 2022

i wolud like to obtain 2 more columns for years 2023 and 2024, any clue?

this is what i get:

| Month | NT2022 |
| --- | --- |
| Februery | 5 |
| March | 8 |
| April | 24 |
| May | 29 |
| June | 29 |
| July | 31 |
| August | 36 |
| September | 51 |
| October | 60 |
| November | 66 |
| December | 71 |

this is what i want to get :

| Month | NT2022 | NT2023 | NT2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Januery | 0 | 73 | 158 |
| Februery | 5 | 83 | 161 |
| March | 8 | 83 | 168 |
| April | 24 | 91 | 170 |
| May | 29 | 93 | 173 |
| June | 29 | 105 | 180 |
| July | 31 | 113 | 183 |
| August | 36 | 122 | 189 |
| September | 51 | 127 | 193 |
| October | 60 | 134 | 201 |
| November | 66 | 145 | 203 |
| December | 71 | 152 | 205 |

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the way:

```sql
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%M') as Month,  
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN year(fecha) = '2022' THEN Terminal END) AS NT2022,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN year(fecha) = '2023' THEN Terminal END) AS NT2023,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN year(fecha) = '2024' THEN Terminal END) AS NT2024
From journal where operacion = 'venta' group by DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%m') order by month(fecha)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Keep in mind that we hope that answers here will be useful to others in the future as well.  For that reason, it's better if you include more explanation/commentary around your solution to help others understand it. Thanks!